# Retornar mensagem do else

Tags: python, django, if

Estou fazendo um exemplo bem simples usando Django.

Na minha view tenho o seguinte :

```
def index(request,idade):

    string = '''
        {% if idoso >= 65 %}
            Você já é idoso
        {% else %}
            Você não é idoso
        {% endif %}
    '''
    t = template.Template(string)
    c = template.Context({'idoso':idade})
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```

Mas mesmo que eu passe qualquer valor ele sempre retornará a mensagem do if, ou seja, se eu passar 10 ele retornará: você já é idoso.

Alguém sabe por que isso está  ocorrendo ?

OBS : Uso Django 1.11.

Comment: Beto , verifique se vc está passando de verdade algum valor para sua view, o if pode esta sendo acessado pois esta passando o valor errado.
Você tem o código antecessor desse ? aonde vc define os valores ?

Uma dica: Não seria melhor fazer esse procedimento direto no html ?

Comment: Otávio Reis Perkles, era o tipo da variável que não estava na forma correta para passar pro Context. Estava fazendo dessa forma somente como forma de aprendizado, mas realmente é melhor usar no html.

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente deve esta fazendo algo do tipo:

```
 url(r'^algo/(?P<idade>\d+)/$', views.index)
```

Ao passar o valor por uma regex possa ser que não seja no tipo desejado mesmo que se use o `\d+`, por exemplo.

Para solucionar esse problema é melhor certificar que ele estará no tipo desejado, logo faça :

```
int(idade)
```

Dessa forma o código abaixo funciona bem.

```
def index(request,idade):

string = '''
    {% if idoso >= 65 %}
        Você já é idoso
    {% else %}
        Você não é idoso
    {% endif %}
'''
t = template.Template(string)
c = template.Context({'idoso':int(idade)})
return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
```